# New Folder.exe regsvr.exe deleter in python

Tags: python

I would like to write script which deletes New Folder.exe regsvr.exe viruses:
My algorithm is following:

```
1. Get current working directory
2. check if this directory contains file with extension .exe and size = 646656 bytes
3. if there is/are such file/s delete
recursiveley do the steps 1-3 to subfolders of parent folder
```

I want to ask you about efficiency: Since the root folder may contain thousands folders how it be better implement which imports to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to recursively walk the file tree, and [`os.stat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) on the file paths it gives you as it goes.